# Python loop keeps repeating? Why?

Tags: python, while-loop

```
Another_Mark = raw_input("would you like to enter another mark? (y/n)")

while Another_Mark.lower() != "n" or Another_Mark.lower() != "y":
    Another_Mark = raw_input("Do you want to input another mark? Please put either 'y' or 'n' this time")

if Another_Mark == "y":
    print "blah"

if Another_Mark == "n":
    print "Blue"
```

This is not the actual code I'm using except for the 1st three lines. anyways my question is why does the while loop keep repeating even when I input a value 'y' or 'n', when it asks again if you want to input another mark on the third line. I'm stuck in a infinitely repeating loop.
It shouldn't repeat when the value for Another_Mark is changed to either "y" or "n"

Comment: `not (a or b)` (what you describe) is not the same as `not a or not b` (what your code says).

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
while Another_Mark.lower() not in 'yn':
    Another_Mark = raw_input("Do you want to input another mark? Please put either 'y' or 'n' this time")
```

`not in` operator returns true if given object is not found in the given iterable and false otherwise. So this is the solution you're looking for :)

---

This wasn't working due to boolean algebra error fundamentaly. As Lattyware wrote:

> not (a or b) (what you describe) is not the same as not a or not b
>   (what your code says)

```
>>> for a, b in itertools.product([True, False], repeat=2):
...     print(a, b, not (a or b), not a or not b, sep="\t")
... 
True    True    False   False
True    False   False   True
False   True    False   True
False   False   True    True
```

Comment: While a good solution, a little more explanation would make this answer a lot better.

Comment: I edited in a simple proof (by brute force) showing they are not the same.

Comment: The proof is not clear right away anyway, so it'll be better if op does the boolean calculations himself to verify. But thanks for contribution anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

Your loop logic only every comes out true - if the input is "n", then it's not "y" so it's true. Conversely if it's "y" it's not "n".

Try this:

```
while not (Another_Mark.lower() == "n" or Another_Mark.lower() == "y"):
    Another_Mark = raw_input("Do you want to input another mark? Please put either 'y' or 'n' this time")
```

Comment: Alternatively, `while Another_Mark.lower() != "n" and Another_Mark.lower() != "y":` is also equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic behind the looping is wrong. This should work:

```
while Another_Mark.lower() != "n" and Another_Mark.lower() != "y":
    Another_Mark = raw_input("Do you want to input another mark? Please put either 'y' or 'n' this time")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use AND instead of OR.

It's the way boolean logic distributes.  You can say:

```
NOT ("yes" OR "no")
```

Or you can distribute the NOT into the parenthesis (which is what you're trying to do) by flipping the OR to an AND:

```
(NOT "yes") AND (NOT "no")
```